# Frontend profile search problems

Tags: profile, search-results

When using a profile to search from the frontend (via the listings mode), using the Contact subtype field causes nothing found, even when there are contacts that should be shown.
In other words:

- Fields - individual first & last name, contact - contact subtype
- Searching only by first name works as it should, BUT
- Choosing a contact subtype causes no contacts found, even when there are contacts matching the search
- Filling the last name causes it to be used both as a last name and subtype name, thus nothing is found again

I tried this on the WP demo as well, the above happened. Anyone knows how to fix/avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just successfully replicated this as well.  You've found a bug!

You can report this at http://issues.civicrm.org.  See the page "[Reporting a bug](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting)", starting with step 7.

That said - "CiviCRM is free to use, but not free to write."  Given the limited resources of the core team, they're very unlikely to fix this without someone stepping up to help with either money or a fix.  That's the economics of free software!  So your choice from here is to:

- Submit this to the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).
- Fix the bug yourself, or, assuming you're not a programmer, find someone to fix this bug for you.  Submit the fix to the core team via Github.
- Work around the bug.  Maybe you can restructure your data.  If you were using Drupal, I'd recommend using Drupal Views integration, but unfortunately there's no real equivalent to Views for Wordpress.

Comment: Darn, hoped it was something on my side. Thanks for confirming, issue filled [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18272).