# Mixing Contact sub-type with Individual data in Profile?

Tags: profile, search, custom-search

I have a profile containing first name, last name, employer, and contact sub-type.
When I load the profile in the front-end and click on search, I'm able to see everyone. 
On the first screen, I'm able to search and filter by first name, last name, and employer but not with Contact Sub-Type. It returns "No matches found for:"

Once I'm on the page with the error, I can't do any search. I have to go back to the first page.

This issue is similar to what is described [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10581/frontend-profile-search-problems). But while they were able ti duplicate the error in WP, The same setup is working fine in Joomla Demo site.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Update:
I noticed that the value for "contact_sub_type" in the URL contains a "%01" before and after:
&contact_sub_type=%01Delegate%01
The other fields don't have anything:
&current_employer=schoolname

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.29 on a Joomla 3.8.4